# Como realizar consulta compuesta con orderBy en Firebase Cloud

Tags: firebase, flutter

**Tengo problema al ejecutar el order by por fechaSalida en mí consulta**, me da un error y cuando quito el order by me funciona bien.

La fechaSalida esta en timestamp. Aclarar que cuando ejecuto la consulta sin orderby obtengo resultados.

```
Future<QuerySnapshot> getListaMarcajePorNombre(String nombre) async{

 return dbTrufi.collection('marcaje') 
  .where('chofer',isEqualTo: nombre)
  .orderBy('fechaSalida', descending: true)
  .getDocuments();
 }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tal y como muestra el error, al crear un consulta compuesta con una cláusula de rango que no corresponda a un índice existente, recibirás un error. El mensaje de error incluye un vínculo directo para crear el índice que falta en Firebase console.

> Usa el vínculo que se genera para ir a Firebase console, revisa la
>   información que se propagó automáticamente y haz clic en Crear.

Mas información: [Administra índices en Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing?hl=es-419)

Comment: comentarte que ingrese al vinculo y no me genera ningun mensaje solo muestra el menu de firebase y todo en blanco, gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: Tal vez el link que utilizaste ya habia expirado, genera otro link, utiliza todo el enlace https://console.firebase.google.com/v1..., si eso no funciona, crea un index de manera manual como se muestra en la referencia de mi respuesta.